# Active Admin filters not displaying on screen but present in the html DOM

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, ransack

Filters in AA usually works smoothly. I did notice that when i override scoped_collection method, the whole filter sidebar tends to disappear from the screen but still loaded in the DOM.

I don't have any error in console.
I know AA uses Ransack gem for filters but I don't see where the problem is coming from ?
Did this happen to someone already ?

Comment: Perhaps it is hidden by a CSS rule?